# Why python timeit result is in contradiction with shell's time command?

Tags: python, time, timeit

I'm Not quite sure what I'm missing here, but looks like `time` from shell reports higher values for commands that `timeit` from python report less values for. And practically looks like the `time` numbers are correct. What is happening?

```
time python -m timeit 'd={"i": 1}; d.update({"i": 2, "j": 3, "k": 4})'
```

leads to:

```
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.373 usec per loop (timeit)           
1.54s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 1.545 total (time)
```

---

```
time python -m timeit 'd={"i": 1}; d = dict(d, **{"i": 2, "j": 3, "k": 4})'
```

leads to:

```
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.43 usec per loop (timeit)            
1.77s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 1.778 total (time)
```

---

`time python -m timeit 'd={"i": 1}; d["i"] = 2; d["j"] = 3; d["k"] = 4'`

leads to:

```
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.145 usec per loop (timeit)
5.98s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 5.986 total (time)
```

Comment: Oops! I was missing the third one actually ran 10x more ...

Answer (score 3):

- `time` tells you *how long it takes to run the benchmark*.
- `timeit` tells you *how long it takes to run the code the benchmark is built to measure*.

These are two very different things. `time` includes all the overhead of starting the interpreter; of collecting the statistics on how long your individual benchmarked runs take; of interpreting those results; of doing any additional runs which got thrown out because they were unstable or otherwise statistically unsuitable; of performing garbage collection between timed invocations; etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the result is not in contradiction, as the 3rd case is ran 10x more times at 10,000,000 times while the case 1 and 2 ran 1,000,000 times.